# wicket - PageableListView does not work

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

i am working on wicket, where i am supposed to render vthe view after clicking on the navigation bar nothing happens 
please help me .

```
<div class="colums data" wicket:id="BooksListViewContainer">
```

```
    <div wicket:id="booksListView">
        <div class="col-left data" wicket:id="bookName"></div>
        <div class="col-middle data" wicket:id="author"></div>
        <div class="col-middle data" wicket:id="genre"></div>
        <div class="col-middle data" wicket:id="language"></div>
        <div class="col-middle data" wicket:id="datePublished"></div>
    </div>
    <div wicket:id="navigator" class="navi">xxx</div>
</div>
```

and java:

```
 public class HomePage extends WebPage {

    transient LibaryServices libaryService ;
    Component sortBtns [] ;

public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);
    initPage();
}

private void initPage() {
    libaryService = new LibaryServices();
    add(getBooksListViewContainer());
}

private WebMarkupContainer getBooksListViewContainer(){
    String id = "BooksListViewContainer" ;
    WebMarkupContainer c = (WebMarkupContainer) get(id);
    if (c != null)
        return c;

    final WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer(id);
    container.add(getBooksListView());
    container.add(getNavigator());
    container.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    return container;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private PageableListView<Book> getBooksListView() {
    String id = "booksListView";
    PageableListView<Book> c = (PageableListView<Book>)get(id);
    if (c != null)
        return c;
    final PageableListView<Book> booksListView = new PageableListView<Book>(id, libaryService.getBooks(), 4) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Book> listBookItem) {
            Book book = (Book) listBookItem.getModelObject();

            listBookItem.add(new Label("author", book.getAuthor()));
            listBookItem.add(new Label("bookName", book.getBookName()));
            listBookItem.add(new Label("language", book.getBookLanguage()));
            listBookItem.add(new Label("genre", book.getGenre()));
            listBookItem.add(new Label("datePublished", book.getDatePublished()));

            listBookItem.setVisible(listBookItem.isVisible()&&
                        book.isShouldBeDisplayedAfterPassFilter());     
        }
        @Override
        protected IModel<Book> getListItemModel(
                IModel<? extends List<Book>> listViewModel, int index) {
            return super.getListItemModel(listViewModel, index);
        }
    };
    booksListView.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    booksListView.setMarkupId(id);
    return booksListView;
}
    public SortingDataUtil getSortingDataUtil(){
    return SortingDataUtil.getInstace();
}

private AjaxPagingNavigator getNavigator() {
String id = "navigator";
AjaxPagingNavigator navigator = (AjaxPagingNavigator) get(id);
if (navigator == null) {
    navigator = new AjaxPagingNavigator(id, getBooksListView()) {
    @Override
    protected void onAjaxEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        super.onAjaxEvent(target);
    }
    };
    navigator.setOutputMarkupId(true);
}
return navigator;
}
```

}

and this is the Exception I am getting

Unexpected RuntimeException

```
  Last cause: Argument 'component' may not be null.
 WicketMessage: Method onRequest of interface      org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at      org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.navigation.paging.AjaxPagingNavigationLink$1@321af6fe on component [AjaxPagingNavigationLink [Component id = pageLink]] threw an exception
```

Stacktrace

Root cause:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 'component' may not be null.
 at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Args.notNull(Args.java:41)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestHandler.add(AjaxRequestHandler.java:226)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.navigation.paging.AjaxPagingNavigator.onAjaxEvent(AjaxPagingNavigator.java:152)
 at com.wicketlibary.HomePage$3.onAjaxEvent(HomePage.java:146)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.navigation.paging.AjaxPagingNavigationBehavior.onEvent(AjaxPagingNavigationBehavior.java:82)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:131)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:603)
```

EDIT:   my version is

```
  <wicket.version>6.6.0</wicket.version>
```

Comment: From your stacktrace its hard to trace the bug, but if something is null it should be quite easy to catch this on the debugger.

Comment: I coughet it , and understood the problem , i think it's rather problem with the inferstrascture or a problem in the above
i think it's wicket bug ... but if someone finds me wrong tell me

Comment: Well from the stacktrace it looks like the AjaxPagingNavigator is constructed using null as a second parameter. From your sourcecode I can't quite figure out how this is supposed to happen but as you're using a pattern (get(id)-return-if-not-null-construct-otherwise) that seems questionable to me there might be issues with that...

Answer (score 0):

You should create a quickstart and submit if you think its a bug.

Before you do that I would change the way you are getting the reference to the PageableListView and instead create a class variable, set it and use it when creating the AjaxPagingNavigator.  Did you use debug to ensure that "c" is not null when being called from the AjaxPagingNavigator.  I have this working in my environment using same wicket version as you.  The only difference in my code is that I dont get my variables by calling get(id)

Comment: so what is your best practice on getting Component ?

Comment: I guess it depends, you can have a component as a class variable as long as you are using models correctly that shouldn't be a big deal.  You can also pass the reference around to the different methods.  Did you solve your issue?